# How can I use OR in a left join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

Maybe there's a better way to do this... I have a table of member friend requests.  The columns are request_id, author_id, recipient_id, status(accepted or denied).  I also have a members table whose id is linked to the author or recipient.  I want to get a list of a member's friends by selecting from the members table and then joining the requests table.  Since the member can be either the author or the recipient of any, some, or none of the requests, a simple LEFT JOIN member_requests AS r ON member_id = r.author_id wouldn't work.  How can I write a query that will do this?

```
SELECT
     m.member_id, m.display_name
     r.author_id, r.recipient_id, r.status
FROM members AS m
LEFT JOIN member_requests AS r ON m.member_id = r.recipient_id
WHERE r.status = 1 --Accepted
ORDER BY m.display_name
```

Comment: Try this `ON (m.member_id = r.recipient_id OR m.member_id = r.author_id) WHERE ...`

Comment: I don't see the logic in doing a `left join` here.  You are going to get all the members anyway, regardless of the conditions in the `on` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an OR in your left join, like so:

```
LEFT JOIN member_requests AS r 
    ON m.member_id = r.recipient_id
      OR m.member_id = r.author_id
```

However, your where clause also needs to be altered:

```
SELECT
     m.member_id, m.display_name
     r.author_id, r.recipient_id, r.status
FROM members AS m
LEFT JOIN member_requests AS r 
    ON (m.member_id = r.recipient_id
      OR m.member_id = r.author_id)
    AND r.status = 1 //Accepted
ORDER BY m.display_name
```

When you left join table A to table B, and then specify a restriction in your where clause on table B, you convert your left join into an inner join. Typically, a left join to table B would yield some null values, since table A might have records that don't join to table B. But if you say 'where table B.value = x', you restrict your join to only rows in which table A joins to table B, and furthermore to rows in which 'B.value = x'. The join is then evaluated as an inner join, rather than a left outer.

Comment: Ahh I had no idea you could use OR in a left join!  This worked beautifully!